# How to store daily snapshot of site statistics in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, statistics

I'd like to chart daily page views/edits/numbers of pages in existence on a site with MediaWiki and Semantic MediaWiki installed.  I have shell access to the site.
How can you automate the storage of time-series of statistics?

Comment: You could look at how wikiapiary.com does it.

Comment: Alternatives may involve a server-side routine that sends regular updates to some external monitoring system such as munin, ganglia, graphite..